# Perform validation with OR condition using validators

Tags: angular

I have one input field that accepts either email address or phone number as input. If user enter email address then want to validate using validators.email and if user enters phone number then want to validate with pattern that accept only  numbers like validatiors.pattern(regularexpression). I have used reactive form validations.

how can we do this?

Comment: As this is not common case to keep to different types in one, you should create your own custom validator, which should have implemented that logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ng-pattern](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern) .

Example,

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="..." ng-required="requireTel"
    ng-pattern="phoneNumPattern" />
```

**Script**

```
$scope.phoneNumPattern = (function() {
    var regexp = /^\(?(\d{3})\)?[ .-]?(\d{3})[ .-]?(\d{4})$/;
    return {
        test: function(value) {
            if( $scope.requireTel === false ) {
                return true;
            }
            return regexp.test(value);
        }
    };
})();
```

Comment: thanks, but i'm using angular 4 with validators in reactive form. can you please update answer using angular 4.